# Java Stream reducing multiple lists by condition

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream, reduce

On java 1.8 or above is possible reducing list of list?

I need numbers arrays when the sum of numbers cannot exceed 8.

Example: I have a following list: [ 2 , 4 , 6 ].
The return can be [ [ 2 , 4 ] , [ 6 ] ] or [ [ 2, 6 ],[ 4 ] ].

I tried the following way:

```java
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(2,4,6);
        nums.stream()
            .filter((p) -> p <= 8)
            .map(Collections::singleton)
            .reduce(new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(), (s1, s2) -> {
                int sumS1 = s1.stream().reduce(0, (n1, n2) -> n1 + n2);
                if (sumS1 == 8 ) return s1;
                int sumS2 = s1.stream().reduce(0, (n1, n2) -> n1 + n2);
                if (sumS1 + sumS2 <= 8 ) return s1.addAll(s2);
                return s1;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

But I didn't get the expected result.

I did with stateful and accessing the externals variables of control but isn't is best way.

Are there way to build this with Stream and stateless?

I think is opposite the flatMap

Comment: Java Streams is the wrong tool for this. The problem likely needs to be implemented with **recursion**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a combination that satisfies the conditions from all the combinations.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6);
List<List<Integer>> result = IntStream.range(0, 1 << list.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        .filter(j -> (1 << j & i) != 0)
        .mapToObj(list::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .filter(x -> x.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum() < 8)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result);
```

output

```
[[], [2], [4], [2, 4], [6]]
```